# Base R get raster image to fill entire plot area

Tags: r

I'm trying to use base R to plot an image with points overlaid on top, but the image is not taking up the whole plot area. How can I make sure the image is utilizing the whole plot area (essentially making it larger) while still maintaining the spatial boundaries provided by `points()`? For example:

```
library(EBImage)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png"

img <- EBImage::readImage(url)

if (Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Linux") {
  img <- EBImage::rotate(img, 180) %>% 
    EBImage::flop(.)
}

res = dim(img)[1:2]
par(bg = 'grey')
plot(1,1,xlim=c(0,res[1]),ylim=c(res[2],0),asp=1,type='n',xaxs='i',yaxs='i',
     xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='',bty='n')
graphics::rasterImage(img,1,1,res[1],res[2])

points(266,266, pch = 20, cex = 0.75, col="red")
points(329, 266, pch = 20, cex = 0.75, col="red")
points(315, 318, pch = 20, cex = 0.75, col="red")
```

Results in an image like this:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to have the image fill the entire area of the plot (in grey).

Comment: Try `par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, R allows a certain margin around the figure region to allow for labels, axes, and annotations. The default is c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1.

To change these margins, do this:

```
par(bg = 'grey', mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that there were default margins. Thank you!